# merging two video camera into one screen?

Tags: visualization, computer-vision

Hello there community im looking for a way to merge 2 live video feeds onto one screen but still keeping 2 different perspectives from individual cameras in their own windows while in right side of the left camera and the left side of the right camera join both of their feed to create one single frame so that at the end your left with 3 video feeds, far left from left cam middle feed from both cameras and the right cam having its far right side.

i know it can sound confusing so here is a example 
[image]

Comment: I do not understand how this question related to data science.

Comment: well it is computational science and it is dealing with data

Comment: Cross-posted on many other SE sites: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/311442/34181, http://dsp.stackexchange.com/q/29115/5874, http://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/10456/8560, http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/53834/755.
Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068). Each community should have an honest shot at answering without anybody's time being wasted. If you don't get a satisfying answer after a week or so, feel free to flag for migration.

Comment: @jai Pl do not abuse anyone. I agree with the points put forward by d.w, and the  question is also off-topic. No, it does not really come under the domain of `computer vision`

Answer (score 3):

This problem is called *real-time video stitching*. It's pretty hard to do yourself if you're not familiar with computer vision, so [here](http://www.mytechlogy.com/IT-blogs/9702/5-real-time-video-stitching-tools) are some off-the-shelf tools.

edit: If you are looking for a paper: [Stitching videos streamed by mobile phones in real-time](http://research.microsoft.com/apps/pubs/default.aspx?id=112596), or [Real-time photogrammetric stitching of high resolution video on COTS hardware](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpls/abs_all.jsp?arnumber=5326097).

Comment: is this a machine vision approach? i need to build a algorithm not use a app

Comment: this links are of no help

Comment: Why is that? Please go into detail.

Comment: @jai  As Emre has taken the efforts to refine his answer to fit your request (in your comment), pl explain him in detail why the papers have not help you. This would explain him in refining his answer further, if he can!

Comment: @Dawny33 what papers? he directed me to a book store, to buy information, if i have to spend money to get a answer he might as well had directed me to a local university to pay for a degree or perhaps to a online freelancing company.  This is stackExchange you ask a question you get the answer with supporting evidence "this is where the links comes into play"  that was from one link while other link is to a site that talks about current applications that do what im looking todo and this apps aren't even for sale 'not that im looking to buy a app'

Comment: i need to implement the algorithm that makes up the job of stitching and im not even sure stitching is what i actually need